# Detect if a tool is already in execution but ONLY for current user

Tags: bash

Until now I used

```
pidof -o %PPID -x "my-tool"
```

To detect the pid of an eventually running instance of my-tool.

This is the short version of my-tool file, an executable bash script

```
#!/bin/bash 

if pidof -o %PPID -x "my-tool"; then
   echo "Already running"
   exit 1
fi

 ... if not running go on
```

But now  I need to allow *a single instance per user and multiple per machine*, so we can have even 100 my-tool running in the same moment, but only 1 per user.

Note that I need a test to create something like a singleton. If the tool will be started and there is another instance running it will close itself.

**In short: I need that a bash script could detect if itself is already running for the current user and in this case it must exit.**

How to ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `pidof`, there are better tools lie `pgrep`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `pgrep` instead:

```
pgrep -cxu $USER -f my-tool
```

The options used are:

```
   -c, --count
          Suppress  normal  output; instead print a count of matching pro‐
          cesses.  When count does not match anything, e.g. returns  zero,
          the command will return non-zero value.
   -x, --exact
          Only match processes whose names (or command line if -f is spec‐
          ified) exactly match the pattern.
   -u, --euid euid,...
          Only match processes whose effective user ID is listed.   Either
          the numerical or symbolical value may be used.
```

If you want to use this in a bash script that checks if it is already running, you could use `$0`. This expands to the path of the current script (e.g. `/home/username/bin/foo.sh`) but we only need `foo.sh`. To get that, we can remove everything up to the last `/` using bash's [string manipulation tools](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html): `${0##*/}`. This means we can do something like:

```bash
## If there are more than 1 instances of the current script run
## by this user
if [[ $(pgrep -cxu "$USER" "${0##*/}") -gt 1 ]];
then
        echo "Script already running, exiting."
        exit
fi
```

You might also want to consider using lockfiles for this:

```bash
## If the lock file exists
if [ -e /tmp/$USER.foo.lock ]; then
    ## Check if the PID in the lockfile is a running instance
    ## of foo.sh to guard against crashed scripts
    if ps $(cat /tmp/$USER.foo.lock) | grep foo.sh >/dev/null; then
        echo "Script foo.sh is already running, exiting"
        exit
    else
        echo "Lockfile contains a stale PID, continuing"
        rm /tmp/$USER.foo.lock 
    fi
fi
## Create the lockfile by printing the script's PID into it
echo $$ > /tmp/$USER.foo.lock

## Rest of the script here

## At the end, delete the lockfile
rm /tmp/$USER.foo.lock
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43017/discussion-between-terdon-and-realtebo).

Comment: Rather than 
`touch /tmp/$USER.foo.lock`
I would use the PID of the process
`echo $$ >/tmp/$USER.foo.lock`
Then logic could be included to test whether such a process actually exists.

Comment: @MontyHarder indeed, very good suggestion. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: @terdon, had problem with mobile, deleted that comment in the next second. I meant `$(< pidfile)` instead of `$(cat pidfile)` .

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pgrep` fo find if a process is being executed by a specific user and then start the process if not running already by the user:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep -u "$USER" my-tool &>/dev/null; then
    echo 'You already have my-tool running'
else
    /path/to/my_tool
fi
```

The environment variable, `$USER`, will be expanded to the currently logged in user i.e. the user running the script. As we are only interested in whether the `my-tool` is running or not, so just using the exit status directly with `if` construct is enough.

Use this script as a wrapper for starting `my-tool` and make the users use this only or rename it as `my-tool` and rename the original `my-tool` to something else (and change the name inside the script too).

Comment: I cannot make a wrapper, long history, ... how can I exclude the current process PID ?

Comment: @realtebo ummm..exclude PID meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Try it with this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
MyProcessName=$(ps -p $$ -o args=)
Mypid=$$
AllPids=$(pgrep -fu "$(whoami)" "$MyProcessName")
AllPids=$(tr "\n" ' ' <<<"$AllPids")
Pids=$(sed "s/$Mypid//" <<<"$AllPids")
echo "$$: Instances including itself: $AllPids"
echo "$$: Instances different from itself: $Pids"
```

It is important to not write `pgrep|tr` because this would fork into a same named shell.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the command you wish to run in a flock to ensure that only one copy runs at a time. Use a lock_file stored within a user's home directory tree so that each user has their own lock file. For example:

```
lockfile = "~/lockfile"
(
 if flock -n 200; then
    command
 else
    echo "Could not get lock $lock_file
 fi
) 200>$lock_file
```

'command' can be any bash command or script.

`man flock` gives examples of usage

Comment: Really, I didn't know `flock` command at all